# What to do about the similar tags [jasmin] and [jasmine]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tags [jasmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin) and [jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine) refer to two different things that have nothing to do with each other. [jasmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin) is about [an assembler for the JVM](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) while [jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine) is a [JavaScript testing framework](http://jasmine.github.io/).

Nevertheless the tag [jasmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin) is used in countless places where [jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine) should have been used (and maybe vice-versa). Both tags do have a description so if users would be reading the description they'd notice, but obviously they do not.

What can be done to distinguish the two better? Maybe rename to [jasmine-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine-js) and [jasmin-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin-assembler)?

Comment: There is also [Jasmin SMS Gateway](http://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Some questions are related to it. We have [tag:jasmin-sms] for it.

Comment: I've retagged the questions properly for [tag:jasmin] and [tag:jasmine]. But there still will be disambiguation for new questions..